# Uploading file in a form on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have tried all solutions but I can't tell what's wrong. Codeigniter keeps telling me that there's no file uploaded. I created the folder at the root of the project. I've seen other similar questions but I can't manage to make it work with their solutions.

This is my controller:

```
public function index() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'required|trim|max_length[45]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('type_id', 'type', 'required|trim|max_length[11]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('stock', 'stock', 'required|trim|is_numeric|max_length[11]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'price', 'required|trim|is_numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('code', 'code', 'required|trim|max_length[45]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'description', 'required|trim|max_length[45]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('active', 'active', 'required|trim|max_length[45]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('unit_id', 'unit', 'required|trim|max_length[45]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'File', 'trim');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error">', '</span>');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) { // validation hasn't been passed
            $this->load->view('product/add_view');
        } else { // passed validation proceed to post success logic
            // build array for the model
            $form_data = array(
                'name' => set_value('name'),
                'type_id' => set_value('type_id'),
                'stock' => set_value('stock'),
                'price' => set_value('price'),
                'code' => set_value('code'),
                'description' => set_value('description'),
                'active' => set_value('active'),
                'unit_id' => set_value('unit_id')
            );

            $config = array(
                'upload_path' => "./uploads/",
                'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
                'overwrite' => TRUE,
                'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
                'max_height' => "768",
                'max_width' => "1024"
            );
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config); //Make this line must be here.
            $imagen = set_value('userfile');
            // run insert model to write data to db

            if ($this->product_model->product_insert($form_data) == TRUE) { // the information has therefore been successfully saved in the db
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload($imagen)) {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    $this->load->view('product/add_view', $error);
                } else {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    $this->load->view('product/add_view', $data);
                }
            } else {
                redirect('products/AddProduct', 'refresh');
                // Or whatever error handling is necessary
            }
        }
}
```

This is my view (just showing the part that matters)

```
<?php // Change the css classes to suit your needs    

$attributes = array('class' => '', 'id' => '');
echo form_open_multipart('products/AddProduct', $attributes); ?>

<p>
    <label for="picture">Picture <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <?php echo form_error('userfile'); ?>
<?php echo form_upload('userfile')?>
    <br/>
</p>

<p>
        <?php echo form_submit( 'submit', 'Submit'); ?>
</p>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**EDIT**: Applying the modification from the answer I get an error 500.

Comment: if you get `The localhost page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500` possible error on your syntax

Comment: there should be 3 closing curly braces at the end of your function index()

Comment: What kind of error could it be? Rules? the $config array?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to work on your code. and it worked on me after this changes

```
$config = array(
    'upload_path' => "./uploads/",
    'upload_url' => base_url()."uploads/", //  base_url()."/uploads/", //added
    'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
    'overwrite' => TRUE,
    'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
    'max_height' => "768",
    'max_width' => "1024"
);

$this->load->library('upload'); //changed
$this->upload->initialize($config); //Make this line must be here.
$imagen = userfile; // $_FILES['userfile']['name'] //changed
```

If you get The localhost page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 possible error on your syntax, I just add 1 more `}` at the end of your code. You can check phpinfo() for other information. Also, there might be a problem on your file locations maybe the address you specified or the permissions if your running this on server.

Comment: I've been testing on Windows 10 using php 5.4.31. The only thing that fails is the upload.